# Java - when clicking the mouse, the tick() loop causes more than one action

Tags: java, swing, loops, mouseevent, mouselistener

I am making a game in java and I have added mouse input. Here is my code.

```
public class MouseInput implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

public static boolean leftPressed;
public static boolean rightPressed;

public MouseInput(){

}
public void tick(){
    if(leftPressed){
        System.out.println("left pressed");
    }
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
        leftPressed = true;

    }else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
        rightPressed = true;

    }
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
        leftPressed = false;
    else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
        rightPressed = false;

}
```

I removed all of the excess code that isn't involved in this question such as getters, setters and abstract methods.

When I run this and I click what I see is

```
left pressed
left pressed
left pressed
left pressed
left pressed
left pressed
```

several times.
This is because it is inside of the tick method, which updates 60 times per second. What can I change to the mousePressed and mouseReleased methods to only make it one

```
left pressed
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Based on your example there is no correlation between the mouse event handler methods and the `tick` method. From where is it called?

Comment: and what will be te purpose of the `tick()` method?

Comment: You've left out some important detail from your question, including as @TimothyTruckle mentions above, the purpose of the tick method, as well as more background about your GUI and its current observed and desired behaviors. Please help us by filling in the gaps in our knowledge.

Comment: So you're abandoning this question, essentially throwing out all Timmy's help and consideration in trying to answer it. That's not fair to him or to this community. Please delete the new question and improve **this** question.

Comment: Sorry for all of the inconvenience, it was wrong of me to make a new question. I have deleted it. @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

> What can I change to the mousePressed and mouseReleased methods to only make it one

fore the time being you can obviously move the sysout statement from the `tick()` method to `mousePressed()`

```
public void tick(){
    if(leftPressed){
    }
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
        leftPressed = true;
        System.out.println("left pressed");

    }else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
        rightPressed = true;

    }
}
```

Forethemore you should not repead the code in `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()` choose either one that fits your need better.

To avoid empty method implementations you may inherit from [MouseAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) which has empty methods implementations for several Mouse releted listeners

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help
I managed to solve my issue by following this game tutorial on YouTube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2RzIK3YEtI